# Why are Android libraries not found in Visual Studio 2019 (XAMARIN)

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I was working on a project a few days ago and everything was ok. I just got a new PC a couple days ago and I wanted to work on it, but for some reason all Android libraries were not found. For example:

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Net;
```

I had both Java and Android SDK installed and in my system path env. I also noticed this weird yellow warning in my Dependencies -> Assemblies -> Mono.Android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm posting the solution because it took me two full days to figure out the solution.

If you go to yourprojectname.csproj file you can se this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Mono.Android">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v9.0\Mono.Android.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

And this is the problem. The path to the Mono.Android.dll was never found, as my Visual Studio installation was on C:/... while my project was on D:/...

On my old laptop I only had one disk so the problem never occured. I fixed this by moving my project to the same disk that my Visual Studio installation is on (in my case to C:/... )

Comment: Why don't use nuget for Xamarin packages?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I did use nuget packages :D

Comment: @sesmajster then your packages should *not* be in that path. Default is `YourApplication/packages`. All nugets will be stored there, project wise of course; therefore all paths inside your csproj should be relative - allways!
I suggest you find out, why that path got wrong - i.e. manual changes? Dont do this!

Comment: @nilsK I did not do any manual changes. I just cloned the project from git on my new computer. And everything else was ok, just this Mono.Android was broken.

Comment: The Hint Path shouldn't be necessary. If you have that reference, the Xamarin.Android targets will figure out which Mono.Android.dll to use based on TargetFramework used in the project. What kind of project are you adding Mono.Android to?

Comment: @Cheesebaron I don't know why or how this is how it is. It was all auto-generated. I were adding Mono.Android to Xamarin.Forms project. But as I'm saying, on my old computer there was no problems with this.

Comment: Right, but that reference is in the Android App project?

Comment: @Cheesebaron no, this reference is in xamarin app project. My structure goes like: NAME - NAME.Android - NAME.iOS. This is in NAME.Dependencies.Assemblies -> Mono.Android